# Multi-user text mode runlevel in Ubuntu

Tags: debian, ubuntu, runlevel

I use Ubuntu as a server, and I want to change its runlevel to be full multi-user text mode (like init 3 in RedHat).

Using `runlevel` command, I see that am running  `N 2` which is Graphical multi-user with networking based on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel)  wiki entry.

So I'm wondering, is *1- Single-user mode* in Ubuntu the equivalent for *3- Full multi-user text mode* in RedHat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu there are no different runlevels for multiuser with or without GUI. If you want to disable the graphical interface you would have to disable GDM/XDM. How to do this is described in [this Ask Ubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196603/how-to-remove-the-graphical-user-interface)

Answer (score 1):

The information from the other poster back in 2014 is incorrect, in the era of systemd-enabled Ubuntu. All you need to do is run `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` and you'll get what you were asking for.